# NSmutable array returns null in subviewcontroller: iphone objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, uitableview

I have a root view controller that I'm adding a subviewcontroller to.

Rootviewcontroller: I'm trying to add a value from a dictionary as the sole member of the `moviewController.list` `NSMutableArray`. However its not getting added and the NSlog is telling me that the "`list: (null)`"

```
for (id key in dictionary) {

    MovieController *movieController = [[MovieController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    movieController.title = key;


    [movieController.list addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:key]];
    NSLog(@"list: %@",[movieController.list count]); //<<<<


    [array addObject:movieController];
    [movieController release];
}
```

in the subviewcontroller (MovieController) I create the list thats used to display the items in the table as:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.list = array;

    [array release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Why is it that I can't addobject in the rootviewcontroller? The only way I can get the list to display in the MovieController is to `initWithObjects` at the time of instantiation.

Regards

Sapatos

Answer (score 0):

The `-count` returns an integer, not an ObjC object, so you should never format it with `%@`. Use `%d` instead:

```
NSLog(@"list: %d",[movieController.list count]); //<<<<
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the *list* property in the -viewDidLoad method but this method is not called until the view is loaded. Since the -viewDidLoad method is not called, *list* remains uninitialized at the time you add the object as follows,

```
[movieController.list addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:key]];
```

I would suggest you initialize the *list* property in the initializer rather so that the list is initialized by the time you add the object.